# Unknown expected value and variance in a reproductive property of distribution problem.

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve the following problem:
When the random variables X and Y are mutually independent and follow the same normal distribution $N( \mu ,\sigma^2)$, where $\mu$ is the expected value and $\sigma^2$ is the variance, we have to find the probability distribution that follows $U=2X+3Y$.
This is the problem. I would think that the answer develops as follows:

$X\sim N( \mu ,\sigma^2)$

$Y\sim N( \mu ,\sigma^2)$

$2X+3Y\sim N(5\mu,13\sigma^2)$

From here on I would need the values of the expected value and variance, but I do not have them. Is it impossible without any data? Or is there another way to look for both values? Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: You did well and cannot get any further than this result if other info lacks.

Comment: You can say that that the expected value is $5\mu$ and the variance $13\sigma^2$. So your answer is not a number. But this is not problematic.